# GCP Https Load Balancer SSL Certificate

Tags: https, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, load-balancing

I am trying to create a Https load balancer using yaml and Jinja files on GCP deployment manager. But I am not sure how to provide SSL certificate. In the "sslCertificates" of "compute.v1.targetHttpsProxy", it expects the value to be URL to sslCertificates. How do i create an URL for the SSL certificate. Earlier, I was trying to provide the certificate itself in the field but I get an error saying "The URL is malformed".

Please help if anyone knows how to solve this.

Comment: I suspect that answer to this question is the same as the format needed for the API call for setSSLCertificates. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find that information. I'm asking a separate question about that.

Comment: Someone pointed me to the correct answer someplace else, which is that the URL you need for the API, and presumably for Google Deployment Manager, is the one pointed to by "selfLink" in when listing sslCertificates in GCP. It looks like:

[https]://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<projectid>/global/sslCertificates/<certname>"

Answer (score 1):

You have to use gcloud to upload the certificate to Google Cloud, like this:

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create [SSL_CERTIFICATE] \ 
--certificate [CRT_FILE_PATH] --private-key [KEY_FILE_PATH]
```

You need the certificate to be PEM encoded. After this you can attach [SSL_CERTIFICATE] to your load balancer. Do this for each of the certificates you want to attach to it.

The documentation for this is [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates).

Edit:

To add to this incomplete answer, in case you in ever have a doubt of what API call to make while within Google Cloud just run the equivalent gcloud command with the flag `--log-http` and review carefully the results. The gcloud SDK is making the API calls you need and this flag will output all that happens and what endpoints and in which format you need to call to reproduce that.

Comment: This isn't really a good answer to the question. The poster asked how to attach a certificate to a load balancer in GCP Deployment Manager, and you told them how create a certificate with gcloud. You also told them you have to create the certificate with gcloud, which isn't true either; the API works fine. Unfortunately, I don't know the correct answer to the question, because the URL format for a GCP SSL certificate needed for the API call (which I assume is what GCP is looking for here) isn't documented anyplace I can find it.

Comment: Added extended answer. Something about teaching to fish or whatever.